# Running Standard Java Program in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I have craeted a standard java application and want run it to android studio. Is this possible without changing in the java code ?

Answer (score 0):

Android is not 100% pure Java codes. you might able to run it with few modifications. for example GUI System is different. You cant use j2EE .

refer to android official guide to learn android APIs -https://developer.android.com/reference/org/w3c/dom/Document.html